# Cross-domain AJAX - not getting the desired result

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to ajax a form to a different domain using the jquery.xdomainajax.js plugin and having issue getting the desired HTML back (follow up to this question: [Display form result in same page with only client-side script possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158834/display-form-result-in-same-page-with-only-client-side-script-possible/20158893?noredirect=1))

The destination script checks the user id against the membership database, and redirects to an error page if the user has already submitted the form, or redirect to a thank you page if the entry is valid.

Using the script below, I get back the HTML of the ORIGINAL page on which the form is displayed, not the error page or the thank you page. If I change the dataType from "text" or "html" to "jsonp", I get a parse error as expected, but the associated HTML is actually desired HTML. I am not quite sure why.

Any help would be much appreciated!

PS: I do not have control over anything in the remote server.

```
$.ajax({
        type: settings.postType, //GET
        url: settings.tourl,
        data: aForm.serialize(),
        dataType: settings.type, //text or HTML
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert(data.responseText);
            settings.success(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //alert(errorThrown);
            console.log(textStatus);                                                 
            settings.error();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Should your request type be a POST instead of a GET?  Generally form info will be sent with a POST.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the response. It seems I can't use POST without running into the cross-domain issue since I do not have control over the remote server code. I tried using GET with just the HTML (no ajax), and it seems to work correct so I was hoping GET would work with AJAX as well.

Comment: Makes sense re: cross domain permissions.  What determines original vs. desired HTML on the page you're making the request to?  Does it differ by a querystring parameter or something?

Comment: I'm out for the night.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain.  I think it'll answer your questions.  Good luck!